# ui slider массив определенных значений

Tags: jquery, slider, ui

Есть такой слайдер:

```
$(function () {
    // слайдер 2
    $(".slider-range1").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 50,
        max: 1800,
        values: [50, 1800],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            if(ui.values[1] - ui.values[0] < 20 ) return false;
            $('input[name="weight_min"]').val(ui.values[0] + " г.").attr('data-val', ui.values[0]);
            $('input[name="weight_max"]').val(ui.values[1] + " г.").attr('data-val', ui.values[1]);
        }
    });
    $('input[name="weight_min"]').val($(".slider-range1").slider("values", 0) + " г.");
    $('input[name="weight_max"]').val($(".slider-range1").slider("values", 1) + " г.");

});
```

Как задать ui slider-у массив определенных значений - `[30,50,100,125,250,500 ]`
И передвигать бегунки только по этим значениям ?

[Slider-demo](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range)

[Slider Widget доки](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/)

Comment: ссылка на доки слайдера и/или демо будет не лишней

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если используется только один ползунок то можно попробовать так:

```
$(function() {
    var valMap = [0, 40, 50, 63, 90, 110, 125, 140, 160, 225, 250];
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        min: 1,
        max: valMap.length - 1,
        value: 0,
        slide: function(event, ui) {                        
            $("#amount").val(valMap[ui.value]);                
        }       
    });
    //$("#amount").val(valMap[ui.value]);
})
```

html:

```
<input type="text" id="amount" value="40" />
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

Если используется два ползунка, то

```
$(function() {
    var valMap = [0, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500];
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: valMap.length - 1,
        values: [0, 1],
        slide: function(event, ui) {                        
            $("#amount").val('Miles: ' + valMap[ui.values[0]] + ' - ' + valMap[ui.values[1]]);                
        }       
    });
    $("#amount").val('Miles: ' + valMap[$("#slider-range").slider("values", 0)] + ' - ' + valMap[$("#slider-range").slider("values", 1)]);
});
```

В данном случае `valMap[ui.values[0]]` и `valMap[ui.values[1]]` будут вашими `$('input[name="weight_min"]')` и `$('input[name="weight_max"]')` соответственно

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, вот пытался переделать по вашему примеру, но чёт не выходит.
https://jsbin.com/puziqebicu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @amijin Потому, что я в примере использовал `id`, а вы класс... Измените `$("#slider-range1")` на `$(".slider-range1")`. А если на странице будет только один слайдер, то лучше через `id` делать. имхо